# Can a command pattern be used as a Unit of work pattern?

Tags: c#, architecture

If I understand a Unit of work pattern correctly, it basically aggregates all the data store calls so that they would execute in one 'transaction', whether that may be a sql transaction or something that you've written by hand.

My question is that can you implement a command pattern to accomplish the same?  For example, in the business layer you would have actions such as, CreateUserAction or CreateOrder, which could hit several tables in order to perform the action successfully.  Isn't that the same as a UoW?

Comment: I would say you can use a series of command objects to enable the rollback of them within a unit of work. Commands can be persisted, but I have never seen an implementation that persists the unit of work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a command can encapsulate the entirety of a unit of work.  However, not all commands obviously do that, and as mentioned you could have a series of commands that all share the same unit of work.

It really depends on the granularity of your commands and what is attempting to be accomplished.

Comment: As far as granularity is concerned, my plan is to have a transactions within each command and bascially have the commands encapsulate the sql calls to the DAL inside the command.  So, in that fashion, the commands work like a unit of work.  When I see the command pattern and unit of work, they seem to do the same thing.  They both execute code around some business context.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand a Unit of work pattern correctly, it basically
>   aggregates all the data store calls so that they would execute in one
>   'transaction', whether that may be a sql transaction or something that
>   you've written by hand.

`UnitOfWork` does not aggregare data store calls. It does not have any methods implemening any bussiness logic of your application.

`UnitOfWork` should have means for tracking changes, your application makes to the database so that all of them can be applied inside a single transaction.

Traditionally, we change database through changing fields of our models. So, `UnitOfWork` looks like [this](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).

> My question is that can you implement a command pattern to accomplish
>   the same? For example, in the business layer you would have actions
>   such as, CreateUserAction or CreateOrder, which could hit several
>   tables in order to perform the action successfully. Isn't that the
>   same as a UoW?

This is not UnitOfWork in my opinion. This is just a command pattern, which changes database directly. Your actions can only be executed. They are not tracked for changes (no clean/dirty states), they cannot be deleted. What you have looks like a `Queue` for database-changing `Commands`.

To involve `UnitOfWork` your commands could create instances of your bussiness logic models and then pass those to `registerNew()` / `registerDirty()` methods of `UnitOfWork`.

Answer (score 0):

We currently post commands in batches (for instance all commands that have been created before a user hits Save), and only at the end of the batch processing we validate affected entities and only persist them if validation is successful. Thus we achieve a transactional integrety of the set of commands, that does not require a roll-back because we simply don't persist (for EF we don't call SaveChanges() on the context) if validation fails.